# How to concatenate a table name in Hive SQL from a variable

Tags: sql, hive

I'm trying to do the following:

```
%sql

set target_table_name = 'clickstream'
select ${hivevar:target_table_name};
```

and then create a table:

```
%sql

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `database_blah.${hivevar:target_table_name}`  (
  event_header_event_id string
...
)
USING parquet partitioned by (x, y);
```

But I'm getting the error:

```
AnalysisException: `database_blah.` is not a valid name for tables/databases. Valid names only contain alphabet characters, numbers and _.
```